# default value of "value" in primitive types

Tags: c#, vb.net

primitive types (integer, string, etc) are now classes.  However to access the value of the class you just use the object name (ex, x=y).  It isn't necessary to refer to a property of the class (x.value = y.value).

To implement an abstract data class (say inches), we need a value property so if we have
dim x as inches (our class)
we have to use:
x.value = 3

is that fair?

Comment: Could you give some code examples of the things you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

You have the option of overloading the assignment operator to suite your needs.

For example:

```
public static implicit operator Inches(int value)
{
   return new Inches(value);
}
```

At which point you would then be able to do something like so:

```
Inches something = 4;
```

Comment: Just so you know, the question is tagged as "vb.net".

Comment: @Andrew: Is this not doable in VB.NET? Or are you just pointing that out because the answer was given in C#?

Comment: @Andrew Hare - also tagged as C#

Comment: @Andrew It's not tagged in both VB.NET and C#?

Comment: sorry, Joseph - I thought c# had the same problem as vb.net since I was really interested in the vb.net solution.  vb.net doesn't allow you to override the assign as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are looking for is an implicit conversion to and from a primitive type.  Joseph gave part of the C# code, here is the VB.Net version (with both operator types)

```
Class Inches
    Private _value As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer)
        _value = x
    End Sub

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal x As Integer) As Inches
        Return New Inches(x)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal x As Inches) As Integer
        Return x.Value
    End Operator
End Class
```

This allows you to write the following code

```
    Dim x As Inches = 42
    Dim y As Integer = x
```

Comment: Thanks Jared, I couldn't find anything on how to do this in VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
class Program
{
    class A
    {
        private int _x;
        public A(int x)
        {
            _x = x;
        }

        public static implicit operator int(A a)
        {
            return a._x;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A(3);
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```